# Protege : Equivalent class definition issue

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, pellet

<s>Seems there is a bug in Protege5</s>. a sample ontology is defined as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_1 -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_1">
        <owl:propertyDisjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_2"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_2 -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_2"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#classA -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#classA">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_1"/>
                <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#has_something_2"/>
                <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#ind_1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2020/0/untitled-ontology-144#ind_1">
        <has_something_1 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">10</has_something_1>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

as you see in below picture, `classA` is defined as two separate axioms `has_something_1 min 1` and `has_something_1 min 1`. and `ind_1` has only one axiom :`has_something_1 10`.

int this case, pellet pellet infer `ind_1` as an instance of `classA`, that is wrong.

[image]

but as depicted in below picture, if `classA` definition was `(has_something_1 min 1 ) and (has_something_2 min 1)`, pellet would not infer `ind_1` as `classA` individual (that is true).

I have already post this issue on [github](https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/930)

[image]

Comment: that's not a bug, you're just wrong here. your ontology states `A EquivalentTo (p1 min 1)` which means `A SubclassOf (p1 min 1)` and `(p1 min 1) SubclassOf A`. Your individual belongs to `(p1 min 1)` so by inference it also belongs to `A`. there is a huge difference between having i) two axioms `A EquivalentTo B1`, `A EquivalentTo B2` and ii) `A EquivalentTo (B1 and B2)`. From i) you get `B1 SubclassOf A` and `B2 SubclassOf A` while ii) leads to `(B1 and B2) SubclassOf A`. Both are **not** semantically equivalent, it's up to you to create your own real world example to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the class with two axioms and defining it with one axiom with a conjunction between class expressions create very different ontologies.

In the first one, the two class expressions are defined equivalent by transitivity, and that's why Pellet is drawing the inference (correctly). In short, the first version has `A equiv B`, `A equiv C`, while the second has `A equiv B and C`. In the first version, `B equiv C` is a valid inference and any individual of B is an individual of C.

Comment: thanks.referring to *A Practical Guide To Building OWL Ontologies edition 1.3* by Matthew Horridge, in exercise 20 there is two class expression for `MargheritaPizza`: `hasTopping some MozarellaTopping`, `hasTopping some TomatoTopping`.and in description says that **a MargheritaPizza is
a NamedPizza that has at least one kind of MozzarellaTopping and at least one
kind of TomatoTopping.**. what do you think of this sentence?

Comment: On page 44-45 of that document, a Margherita is described as a subclass of the property restrictions, and as a subclass of a property restriction having the AND of tomato and mozzarella as filler. My answer holds for equivalence, not subclass axioms.

Comment: I understand your explanation about equivalent class.but Let's look at subclass topic. Do you mean that it can be declared: `MargheritaPizza: hasTopping some MozarellaTopping`, `hasTopping some TomatoTopping` ,  And  explain it in native language as `a MargheritaPizza is a NamedPizza that has at least one kind of MozzarellaTopping and at least one kind of TomatoTopping`? if the answer is yes, so whats the explaination of `(hasTopping some MozarellaTopping) AND (hasTopping some TomatoTopping)` in native language?

Comment: As superclass in a subclass axiom, the natural language and the semantic explanation are the same. Both are defined as necessary, and necessary only, conditions. Having mozzarella and tomato is not a sufficient condition to be a margherita.

Comment: that is true. For subclass it holds `A SubClassOf B` and `A SubClassOf C` is the same as `A SubClassOf (B and C)`. But that does **not** holds for class equivalence, that's the whole point here. Because having `A EquivalentTo B` and `A EquivalentTo C` would **not** be logically equivalent to `A EquivalentTo (B and C)` - it's a much stronger restriction

Comment: @AKSW thanks. this is exactly what i was looking forward to hearing!